# class GraphicsView extends View. setContentView(new GraphicsView) Что в результате отображается на экране, объясните по-русски. прилагаю код

Tags: java, android, canvas, view

В результате выполнения кода при перемещении пальца по экрану Канва перерисовывает Bitmap c новыми координатами. Наследование от View.OnTouchListener не было и вместо onTouch был onTouchEvent. Но я захотел, чтобы слушатель Ontouch повесить на ImageView. Но как видите вместо лояута у меня отображается setContentView(new GraphicsView(this)). Вот что же такое этот new GraphicsView(this)? я понимаю что это объект класса  GraphicsView наследуемый от View, но тогда что он наследует от View? почему он на весь экран и почему цвет фона черный? откуда эти параметры берутся? Как мне на него повесить ImageView,который я назначу слушателем OnTouch?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

        float touchX = 10,touchY= 10;
        private float korX = touchX, korY = touchY, initX=0, initY=0;
        ImageView ar;
        Bitmap bitmap;
        Canvas canvas;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(new GraphicsView(this)); 
            ar.setImageResource(R.drawable.areatouch);
            ar = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }

        public class GraphicsView extends  View  implements View.OnTouchListener{
            public GraphicsView(Context context) {
                super(context);
                ar.setOnTouchListener(this);
            }


            @Override
            protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                Bitmap mybitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.face_box);
                canvas.drawBitmap(mybitmap, touchX, touchY, null);
            }


            public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        korX = touchX;
                        korY = touchY;
                        initX = event.getRawX();
                        initY = event.getRawY();
                       return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        touchX = korX +  (event.getRawX() - initX);
                        touchY = korY +  (event.getRawY() - initY);
                        invalidate();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42318/discussion-on-question-by-turalllb-class-graphicsview-extends-view-setcontentvi).

Answer (score 1):

Вы определяете только один контсруктор с контекстом.
Чтобы создать его через лейат нужно определить остальные 2 конструктора.
Вообще не очень понятно чего вы добиваетесь - почему не наследуетесь от имедж вью?

Comment: поясните пожалуйста , где я определяю один конструктор с контекстом и какие остальные я не определил?  У  меня на экране canvas рисует битмап и как координаты изменяются перерисовывают его в новых координатах. Новые координаты я получаю с Image в виде квадратика внизу экрана. методом OnTouch должен срабатывать только в области этого Image.

Comment: Для начала определите все три конструктора для GraphicsView
` public GraphicsView(Context context) {    super(context); }`
    
   

  ` public GraphicsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {  super(context, attrs); }`
      
   

    `public GraphicsView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }`

Comment: Добавьте график вью в Лейаут `<com.example.alkurop.myapplication.GraphicsView
            android:id="@+id/graphicsView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>`

Comment: Затем поставьте в тот же лейаут ваш имадж вью
Передайте этот леайут в активити
`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        View imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        GraphicsView graphicsView = ((GraphicsView) findViewById(R.id.graphicsView));
        imageView.setOnTouchListener(graphicsView);`